# Smoothing kernel size for box filter

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filter, signal-processing

For box filter in OpenCV, the smoothing kernel size can be defined by ksize parameter in cv2.boxFilter(). I want to know if the ksize is actually the size in the positive X and Y directions or around the origin?
[image: (a) shows a box filter. I am assuming that the corresponding ksize would be (1, 1)]

In the image above - ksize should be (1, 1), correct? Or should it be (0.5, 1)? For a width of, say, 5 in both directions, should the ksize be (5, 5) or (10, 5)? For the said case, I would want the width to be 5 in both positive and negative X directions, and height to be 5 in the y-direction. I think that y should anyways be 5 because negative y for a box filter doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Why does negative y not make much sense? What is the difference between the x and y directions to you?

Comment: In any case, `ksize` is the full width and height of the box, and the box is defined symmetrically around the origin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to find out by testing the boxFilter's impulse response. Let `x` be the 9x9 image

```
>>> x
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Then running boxFilter with ksize=(5,5) as `cv2.boxFilter(x, 6, (5,5))` produces

```
array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])
```

It is like Cris said, ksize is the full width and height of the box, and the filter is centered.

Comment: Nice demo for how to figure stuff out for yourself. Worth an upvote even though you spelled my name wrong. :)

Comment: Thanks for this Pascal!

Comment: The impulse response is the secret weapon for reverse engineering a filter.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry about that! I fixed it.